# Getting Google App Engine and Google Maps API v3 talking

Tags: django, google-maps, google-app-engine

I'm using the Javascript API v3 as follows:

```
(function() {
                window.onload = function(){
                    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(57.8, 14.0);
                    var options = {
                      zoom: 6,
                      center: latlng,
                      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                    }; 
                    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), options);
                }
            })();
```

to load a google maps view - taken from example http://www.svennerberg.com/2009/06/google-maps-api-3-the-basics/. Now I'm keen to pull in long/lat details from the datastore and view these as markers. However I'm not sure of the smartest way to do this, there seem to be some confusing examples that don't help. I'm working on the Google App Engine in Python. Does anyone have any pointers for the simple way of adding markers.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if you are asking how do I store/load Lat/Lng data in the datastore, or if you are asking how do I get the data into javascript, So I'll answer both.

Assuming you are using the original datastore simply create a GeoPtProperty to store the data. When you load the object from the datstore you will have an instance of a GeoPt object with a lat and lon property.

As far as how you get that data into javascript you have several options, depending on your use case, different options may be better for you.
1. You can output the data to your template when you render the rest of the page. How this works exactly will vary depending on your templating system, but you'll want to create a JSON representation of the data using json.dumps or simplejson.dumps
2. You can ask for the data as an AJAX request and return a JSON representation of the data.
3. You can embed the data in your HTML and have your javascript use DOM manipulation to read the data.

Another more advanced method you will want to consider if you are using a lot of markers is to create a KML layer with the data in it and display the KML layer.

Comment: Thanks. I have the GeoPtProperty locations properly stored in the datastore and yes, you do make sense when using the template system - Django in this case to render the page. I'm familiar with using the Django templates but not so much with Javascript.

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty simple, just get the lat/long from your server somehow, either embed it in the page, or get it with an ajax request, then you just create a marker object.

```
var marker - new google.maps.Marker ( { map : <your map variable>,
                                        position : <latlng variable> });
```

Keep the marker object in a variable, and you can update it without recreating it.

```
marker.setPosition(<new latlng>);
```